# Android: Audio card sample rate limit

Tags: android, audio, media

I would like to play a media file which contains a high frequency sounds (inaudible for humans), to repel some animals. My question is: Which is the sample rate limits of any commercial mobile phones? I suppose that is 48 kHz or 44100 Hz. Can I remove this limitation via software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no. The maximum sample rate is dictated by the maximum rate the A/D converters will run at. This won't be above 48kHz in a mobile phone because there's just no benefit.